# vivir a España vs vivir en España

Tags: preposiciones

I have heard the following sentence in the Narcos TV series:

> Prefiero ir a vivir a España.

Is there any difference in meaning between "vivir a España" and "vivir en España" ? Are both equally usual?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In:

- Prefiero ir a vivir **a** España.

only "a" is possible because the verb phrase is "ir a vivir" and the verb "ir" prevails when it comes to choosing the preposition.

When "vivir" is used alone, then "en" will be used.

- Prefiero vivir **en** España.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! One more difference between Portuguese and Spanish.